# Find all words starting with a fix string in a file?

Tags: unix, solaris, rhel

How can I find all the words in my csv file starting with $

My file is like:

```
Test1,$Var1,$varCab1,$Vargab1,Comment1
Test2,$Var2,$varCab2,$Vargab2,Comment2
Test3,$Var3,$varCab3,$Vargab3,Comment3
```

As an output I want

```
$Var1
$varCab1
$Vargab1
$Var2
$varCab2
$Vargab2
$Var3
$varCab3
$Vargab3
```

Comment: did you try anything? Any error or code?

Answer (score 1):

Try following (`grep -oE '\$\w+' filename`):

```
$ cat 1.csv
Test1,$Var1,$varCab1,$Vargab1,Comment1
Test2,$Var2,$varCab2,$Vargab2,Comment2
Test3,$Var3,$varCab3,$Vargab3,Comment3
$ grep -oE '\$\w+' 1.csv
$Var1
$varCab1
$Vargab1
$Var2
$varCab2
$Vargab2
$Var3
$varCab3
$Vargab3
```

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /\$/) print $i; }' 1.csv
$Var1
$varCab1
$Vargab1
$Var2
$varCab2
$Vargab2
$Var3
$varCab3
$Vargab3
```

Comment: This works on RHEL but not working on my SunOS system. I just realize I want a bi-compatible code.

Comment: @PiyushBaijal, I added an alternative solution that use `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` and `grep`:

```
$ tr ',' '\n' < inputfile | grep "^[$]"
$Var1
$varCab1
$Vargab1
$Var2
$varCab2
$Vargab2
$Var3
$varCab3
$Vargab3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'for (m/\$\w+/g) { print $_, "\n" }' < inputfile
```

Or even shorter:

```
perl -ne 'print map("$_\n", m/\$\w+/g)' < inputfile
```

Explanation:

- The regular expression `\$\w+` matches a `$` followed by one or more *word characters*.
- The `m//g` expression returns a list of matches.
- `perl -ne` runs the expression for each file in the input, inserting the line in `$_`, which is then used by the `m//g` expression.